# Indent Fortran source code, propagate indentation down to unindented special lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, text-formatting, fortran

I'm trying to write my own script to improve some auto-formatting before commiting to a remote repository. I use indenting guides in my IDE and the autoformatters available for my language (FORTRAN) do not support indenting empty lines. I essentially want to use `sed` to run through the lines of a file and if the line is empty, then add spaces to the line until it has the same number of spaces as the line **above it** (therefore ignoring the first line). Because I want to use this as part of a pre-commit hook, it would be fantastic if the file was not modified if it passes the requirements.

Example of unformatted file, where `>` corresponds to a space:

```
Start of document - First line is ignored
Second line has text and is therefore ignored
>>>>Third line has four spaces so below (empty line) should have 4 spaces added.

>>>>>>>>Third line has 8 spaces so below (empty line) should have 8 spaces added.

End of document
```

Desired output:

```
Start of document - First line is ignored
Second line has text and is therefore ignored
>>>>Third line has four spaces so below (empty line) should have 4 spaces added.
>>>>
>>>>>>>>Third line has 8 spaces so below (empty line) should have 8 spaces added.
>>>>>>>>
End of document
```

Also, related to this is I would like to indent a line that starts with an exclamation mark **in column 1** (without any spaces before it) to level of the line above (as this is not supported by the autoformatter that I use).

Example of unformatted file, where `>` corresponds to a space:

```
Start of document - First line is ignored
! Second line starts with exclamation mark in column 1 so it is indented to level of above line
>>>>Third line has 4 spaces to start
!This should have 4 spaces added to it because the first character is ‘!’ and above line has 4
>>>>>>>>This line has 8 spaces
>>>>>>>>!This line shouldn’t be changed as it begins with a space, not an exclamation mark.
End of document
```

Desired output:

```
Start of document - First line is ignored
! Second line starts with exclamation mark in column 1 so it is indented to level of above line
>>>>Third line has 4 spaces to start
>>>>!This should have 4 spaces added to it because the first character is ‘!’ and above line has 4
>>>>>>>>This line has 8 spaces
>>>>>>>>!This line shouldn’t be changed as it begins with a space, not an exclamation mark.
End of document
```

I am very new to bash scripting so explanations of how any solutions work would be great and thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: replaced images with text as requested by comment!

Answer (score 1):

A task like this is best done in a language like `awk` or `perl` (because sed doesn't have variables).

The following perl one-liner works for both of your requirements.  I've piped the output into `cat -A` so you can see that the spaces have been added to the start of lines where needed - the `$` indicates the end of each line.

The first statement adds the contents of variable `$spaces` to the beginning of the line (`$_`) if it is empty or starts with a `!` - on the first input line, `$spaces` will be empty. The second statement captures the spaces (if any) at the beginning of the current line into `$spaces`, ready for possible use on the next input line.

Note: this uses `\h`, which means horizontal whitespace (spaces and tabs in ASCII files, and a handful of unicode space chars).  If you want it to use only space characters, change the `\h` to a single space: `($spaces) = (/^( *)/)`.

First input file:

```
$ perl -p -e 'if (/^($|!)/) { $_ = $spaces . $_ };
              ($spaces) = (/^(\h*)/)' input1.txt  | cat -A
Start of document - First line is ignored$
Second line has text and is therefore ignored$
    Third line has four spaces so below (empty line) should have 4 spaces added.$
    $
        Third line has 8 spaces so below (empty line) should have 8 spaces added.$
        $
End of document$
```

Second file:

```
$ perl -p -e 'if (/^($|!)/) { $_ = $spaces . $_ };
              ($spaces) = (/^(\h*)/)' input2.txt  | cat -A
Start of document - First line is ignored$
! Second line starts with exclamation mark in column 1 so it is indented to level of above line$
    Third line has 4 spaces to start$
    !This should have 4 spaces added to it because the first character is '!' and above line has 4$
        This line has 8 spaces$
        !This line shouldn't be changed as it begins with a space, not an exclamation mark.$
End of document$
```

Also note: this prints the file, modified or not, to stdout.  If you want it to modify the original file, then add perl's `-i` option to the command-line - this works like `sed`'s `-i` option. See `man perlrun` and search for `-i\[extension\]` for details) - in particular, note the following:

> Note that because `-i` renames or deletes the original file before creating a new file of the same name, Unix-style soft and hard links will not be preserved.

`git` doesn't seem to care if the file's inode number changes, only if the contents change...but if you need to retain hard-links or just don't want to overwrite the input file if it hasn't been changed, then redirect to a temporary file and only overwrite if `diff` or `cmp` indicates that the temp file is different.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply! This works really well for text files but I realised when trying cat -A that since I am using .f90 files, the raw text of all lines end in '^M'. Can the above be modified to ignore the '^M' at the end of all lines? Also, if the previous line if there is an empty line which should be at 0 indent (the line above that has 0 spaces) then it prints a new line after the empty line. I think this could somehow be altered by only appending $spaces if $spaces is not a new line character but spaces or tabs - although I don't know how to do this!

Comment: @PhilipMoloney Convert your files to Unix text files first with a tool such as `dos2unix`.

Comment: 1. adding `s/\r$//;` to the start if the script (immediately before the `if`) will strip carriage-returns from the end of lines - automatically converting the output from a DOS/Windows text file to unix text file. And if you need the output to be converted back to dos/windows format, also add `; s/$/\r/` to the end of the script.  2. Alternatively, convert your input files to unix text files with `fromdos` or `dos2unix` first. 2. If you change the `\s` to `\h`, it will capture only horizontal white space, not vertical white space like newline \n, form feeds \f, and carriage-returns \r.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```bash
sed -n \
    -e '/^!/ { G; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/; }' \
    -e '/^$/g' \
    -e p \
    -e 's/^\( *\).*/\1/' \
    -e h file
```

This uses a series of `sed` editing expressions to perform the wanted indentations. The script uses the hold space (a secondary non-editable buffer in `sed`) to hold the current indentation as a number of space characters.

The first expression is triggered if the line starts with a `!` in the first position. The expression appends whatever happens to be in the hold space at the end of the current line, with a newline character as a delimiter, and then swaps the two parts of the buffer while removing the newline character.  This indents `!`-lines to whatever the current indentation level is.

The second expression is triggered for empty lines and replaces the empty line with whatever is in the hold space. This takes care of adding the appropriate number of spaces to empty lines.

The third expression outputs the current contents of the editing buffer. We do this explicitly as it is currently correctly indented (either by virtue of having been a `!`-line, an empty line, or by being some other line that we have not modified), and we soon need to modify it to be able to process the rest of the document correctly.

The last two operations truncate the current line at the point where the indentation by spaces ends, and then saves the remaining indentation to the hold space to be used in the next cycle.  Replace the space in the last substitution by e.g. `[[:blank:]]` to match any indentation made with tabs or spaces.